# Tumblr, Wordpress.com and Advertising

Tags: google, tumblr, photos, ads, google-adsense

Am I correct that Tumblr is not a good place for advertising revenue?

For example, I have 2 photoblogs (Tumblr provide a good interface and themes support for photoblogs). People reblog my posts and "like" it, some of them is following... but there is no page viewing at all (by Google Analytics).

I think this is becouse all people are just rebloging and do not visit page directly.

When I look at wordpress.com - there is the same. Rebloging, rebloging, rebloging and posts "timeline" in dashboard.

So, is it correct that this systems are bad for advertising? I want to bring people good content but also I want to get some revenue :)

Maybe I need to get more followers and wait until Search Engines index all content. Get more links, some marketing, adwords? :)

What to do? Wait or reorganize blog to separate domain, using some photoblog engine or wordpress from wordpress.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that Tumblr is a bad place for advertising is that the majority of people are reblogging/liking/viewing from their dashboards. It's only that rare visit from someone new that will give you a view.

Wordpress.com is also a bad place because their TOS does not allow you to place your own ads (since it's free). They'll place ads on your site if your visits get high enough to warrant their placement.

Things to do:

- Tumblr

  - Make sure you know what your sitemap url is by going to `http://yourblogname.tumblr.com/sitemap.xml` and reading the value in the `<loc>` property
  - Submit the sitemap url to [Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en), [Bing](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster), Yahoo(use Bing's), etc. using their individual web admin tools (I've linked the main examples).

This will only allow your tumblog to be better indexed, but doesn't guarantee search result hits.

-- End Answer --

-- Start Suggestion --

I would personally suggest that you get your own domain name or use Blogspot if you're interested in tracking visits and making advertising revenue on your posts. You have better control of the content and the backend, but with a personal domain, you do have the added cost of hosting and maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Maybe I go with own domain. Thank you! :)